# Expected identifier, string or number in Edge on spread operator

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which reduces an array by a key and groups on that key. It works fine in Chrome/Firefox.

In Edge, for `const newNode = { ...curr };` I get an error of `Expected identifier, string or number`

In IE, for `const newData = baseData.reduce((acc, curr) => {` I get a simple `Syntax error`.

My question is whether what I am doing the best way and/or how to get rid of these errors in IE/Edge?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xua0or5h/

```
const d = [
  {"teamID":1,"name":"WMH ED Medics","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":2,"name":"WMH ED Nursing","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":3,"name":"Sedation","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":4,"name":"Safeguarding Level 3","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":5,"name":"Safeguarding Level 2","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":6,"name":"Major Incident","id":1,"username":"WHT\\andrew.bones","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"andrew","surname":"bones","band":"Band 7","role":"Developer","competency":"Kicks","employeeNumber":"123"},
  {"teamID":4,"name":"Safeguarding Level 3","id":276,"username":"WHT\\colin.davids","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"colin","surname":"davids","band":"Band 8","role":"Chap","competency":"Pie","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":5,"name":"Safeguarding Level 2","id":276,"username":"WHT\\colin.davids","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"colin","surname":"davids","band":"Band 8","role":"Chap","competency":"Pie","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":6,"name":"Major Incident","id":276,"username":"WHT\\colin.davids","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"colin","surname":"davids","band":"Band 8","role":"Chap","competency":"Pie","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":2,"name":"WMH ED Nursing","id":277,"username":"WHT\\edward.french","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"edward","surname":"french","band":"Band 9","role":"Lady","competency":"Pizza","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":3,"name":"Sedation","id":277,"username":"WHT\\edward.french","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"edward","surname":"french","band":"Band 9","role":"Lady","competency":"Pizza","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":4,"name":"Safeguarding Level 3","id":277,"username":"WHT\\edward.french","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"edward","surname":"french","band":"Band 9","role":"Lady","competency":"Pizza","employeeNumber":null},
  {"teamID":8,"name":"Digital Team","id":281,"username":"WHT\\gail.johnson","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"stewart","surname":"Johnson","band":"Band 91","role":"Solutions Developer Manager","competency":"Ninja","employeeNumber":"23546329"},
  {"teamID":1,"name":"WMH ED Medics","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"},
  {"teamID":2,"name":"WMH ED Nursing","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"},
  {"teamID":3,"name":"Sedation","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"},
  {"teamID":4,"name":"Safeguarding Level 3","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"},
  {"teamID":5,"name":"Safeguarding Level 2","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"},
  {"teamID":6,"name":"Major Incident","id":283,"username":"WHT\\debra.morris","lastLoggedIn":null,"archive":false,"forename":"debra","surname":"morris","band":"Band 7","role":"Senior Solutions Developer","competency":"LOL","employeeNumber":"23546205"}
];

function reduceJson(baseData,k) {
  const newData = baseData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const node = acc.find((item) => item.id === curr.id);
    if (node) {
      node[k].push(curr[k]);
    } else {
      const newNode = { ...curr };
      newNode[k] = [curr[k]];
      acc.push(newNode)
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return newData;
}
console.log(reduceJson(d,"name"))
```

**UPDATE**

The spread operator is now sorted

```
const newNode = {};
Object.assign(newNode, curr);
```

Comment: [Arrow functions are not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions). [Spread in object literals is not supported in Edge < 79](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: <Pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what spread and rest syntax do.</Pedantry>

Comment: Re your fix for property spread: Beware that `Object.assign` does not exist in IE either, though it can be polyfilled.

Answer (score 2):

IE and Edge are very different things. Also, if you're getting that error with Edge, you're using a very old version of Edge.

IE doesn't support virtually any of ES2015+. That means it doesn't support arrow functions (ES2015) or property spread syntax (ES2018). It has limited and incomplete support for `let` and `const`. That's it.

Edge v44 ("Legacy Edge") and earlier supported some of ES2015+, but IIRC didn't support property spread syntax.

Edge v79 and later (there were no versions between v44 and v79), aka Chromium Edge, are Chromium-based, meaning they have the V8 JavaScript engine, and support property spread.

If you need to support IE, you need to not use ES2015+ features, or to use a transpiler/compiler like Babel to convert them to (roughly) ES5 level syntax so IE can run the code.

If you need to support Legacy Edge, it's a similar task, but there are lots of ES2015+ features you can use (such as arrow functions). Just not property spread and some other features from later editions. For instance, Legacy Edge could handle replacing that property spread with:

```js
const newNode = Object.assign({}, curr);
```

IE doesn't support `Object.assign`, though. (But it can be polyfilled.)